# how to enable touch events or gestures for any LWC component using code level?

Tags: lightning-web-components, touch

We have creating the some custom LWC components, which we need to run on bigger touchscreen panels.
So on those screen, i want to move/perform all activities using touch gestures (Like, touch, double touch, touch drag left/right and so on).

Could you please guide me like how to we will enable these feature in our all possible LWC components?

Answer (score 3):

Since LWC uses standard HTML elements, so the good news is you can use all the touch events supported by web APIs.
You can learn more about touch events from here [Using Touch Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events/Using_Touch_Events)